# How to retain ownership and permissions of System Volume Information

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

Does anyone know of a way of permanently taking ownership and complete control of this folder even through reboots?
I can take ownership of this directory by right-clicking the folder, then properties, then the Security tab, Advanced button, Owner tab, edit..., select my user ID, then OK, OK..., and then selecting complete control. Once this is accomplished, I can browse the System Volume Information folder. This is especially helpful for viewing CHKDSK logs and is (in my opinion) easier than doing so through Event Viewer.
However, after a reboot or shutdown and start, all those permissions are gone, and if I want to take a look at that folder again, I have to go through the whole process again. Being able to permanently take ownership and control would be most useful.

Comment: Workaround: elevated applications can do anything with it. Killing Explorer and launching a new elevated instance would let you look in there (and into a lot of other places too).

Comment: Even if you run Windows Explorer as administrator you cannot open System Volume Information without changing ownership and permissions.

Comment: It works for me (via Task Manager's *Create this task with administrative privileges*), but I'm on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a website [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/about-recycler-and-system-volume-information-folder-in-xp-and-vista/) that has a .reg file that permanently installs a menu item named "Take Ownership" when you right-click on a folder. After installing the .reg file, you can instantly take ownership of a folder without going through all the gyrations otherwise necessary. It's quite handy. Even though it does not allow you to take permanent ownership of a folder, it's orders of magnitude easier. Great tool!
 While not exactly what I was looking for, it's pretty darned close. I'll take it.